# Single Django App Using Two Databases

Tags: django, django-models

How can I configure models in Django which are being hosted in two different databases?

So far, I have 3 databases set up within my great Django environment.  One of my apps uses a [Router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) to automatically send data to the correct database -- this is easily done since this app only deals with that one database.

However, I have another app that uses two different databases.  The app "controls" one of them, but gets data from a second that is updated through another application entirely.

I have tried adding an arbitrary attribute to the model's Meta class, to match against in the router, but this is not allowed in Django (as I discovered).

What data can I provide the model that can be matched against in the router, to know which database to go to?

Comment: I haven't tested this exact situation, but if you know when defining your model class which DB you want to use, you can set an arbitrary attribute to the class itself rather than its Meta class.

Comment: I've tried setting a `db_name` attribute within the regular model, but not all models have the attribute (and system models can't be forced to have it).  My router chokes when it reaches these, despite my attempts to verify the attributes existence.  In this case, how to a verify the attribute that might not be defined?

Comment: You could use `hasattr` to check, or just try/except and catch the exception.

Comment: Answer form so I may lavish with acceptance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know when defining your model class which DB you want to use, you can add an arbitrary attribute to the class itself rather than its Meta class.  In the router, you can then use hasattr to see if the attribute exists (since it won't for built in models), or just try/except and catch the exception.