# Single django app to use multiple sqlite3 files for database

Tags: python, django, django-models, sqlite

I have two models in my django app and I want their tables/databases to be stored in seperate db/sqlite3 files rather than in the default 'db.sqlite3' file.

---

Eg:
my models.py has two classes **Train** and **Bus**, I want them to be stored in **train.db** and **bus.db**

Comment: the relevant question I found was: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573108/single-django-app-using-two-databases) But, I need an **example** of what to write in **models.py**, **settings.py** and any other file that I need to write

Comment: What is the reason for storing them in separate files? Are you aware of the [limitations of using multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/#limitations-of-multiple-databases)?

Comment: I'm aware of that. What I really want to do is to create archive files. As in when I'm generating report in my program at the end of each month I want the table data to be stored in a separate file so that when there is some sort of corrupt in writing data to the file. I don't loose the old one. Saving everything to one file makes it huge and vulnerable.

Comment: Is it not sufficient to configure your DATABASES setting with multiple databases, with different 'NAME' values, then create a database router which routes dependent on the model name? The example in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/) should get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Of course you could always just use `Train.objects.using('train')` for your calls and that would select the correct database (assuming you defined a database called `train` in your `settings.py`.

If you don't want to do that, I had a similar problem and I adjusted my solution to your case. It was partially based on [this blog article](http://diegobz.net/2011/02/10/django-database-router-using-settings/) and the Django documentation for database routers is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing).

With this solution your current database will not be affected, however your current data will also not be transferred to the new databases. Depending on your version of Django you need to either include `allow_syncdb` or the right version of `allow_migrate`.

In settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
     'default': {
         'NAME': 'db.sqlite3',
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
     },
     'train': {
         'NAME': 'train.db',
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
     },
     'bus': {
         'NAME': 'bus.db',
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
     },
}


DATABASE_ROUTERS = [ 'yourapp.DatabaseAppsRouter']

DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {'train': 'train', 'bus': 'bus'}
```

In a new file called database_router.py:

```
from django.conf import settings

class DatabaseAppsRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models for different
    databases.

    In case an app is not set in settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING, the router
    will fallback to the `default` database.

    Settings example:

    DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {'model_name1': 'db1', 'model_name2': 'db2'}

    """

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """Point all read operations to the specific database."""
        return settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.get(model._meta.model_name, None)

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """Point all write operations to the specific database."""
        return settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.get(model._meta.model_name, None)

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """Have no opinion on whether the relation should be allowed."""
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model): # if using Django version <= 1.6
        """Have no opinion on whether the model should be synchronized with the db. """
        return None

    def allow_migrate(db, model): # if using Django version 1.7
        """Have no opinion on whether migration operation is allowed to run. """
        return None

    def allow_migrate(db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints): # if using Django version 1.8
        """Have no opinion on whether migration operation is allowed to run. """
        return None
```

(Edit: this is also what Joey Wilhelm suggested)

Comment: Thanks for putting in the work for the code sample. :) This is precisely what I had in mind.